# Computing expectation of Poisson process which involves covariance

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion

I am looking at a past test with solutions, [for question 8a](http://probability.ca/jeff/teaching/1819/sta447/midterm2sol.pdf), one of the step doesn't make sense to me.
$$
\begin {aligned}
E[(2 + B_2 + B_3)^2] &= E[4 + B_2^2 + B_3^2 + 4B_2 + 4B_3 + 2B_2B_3] \\
&= 4 + Var(B_2) +Var(B_3) + 4E(B_2) + 4E(B_3) + 2Cov(B_2, B_3)
\end {aligned}
$$
for me, I understand that $E(B_2^2) = Var(B_2)+E^2(B_2)$ and  $E(B_3^2) = Var(B_3)+E^2(B_3)$, but I don't see how  $E^2(B_2)+E^2(B_3)+2E[B_2B_3] = 2Cov(B_2,B_3)$, I tried looking up the definition of covariance but nothing's clicking, can anyone direct me towards how I should understand this step? thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's not.  The unwritten property that is being used here is that $\operatorname{E}[B_i] = 0$, thus
$$\operatorname{E}[B_i^2] = \operatorname{Var}[B_i] + \operatorname{E}[B_i]^2 = \operatorname{Var}[B_i]$$ and $$\operatorname{Cov}[B_i, B_j] = \operatorname{E}[B_i B_j] - \operatorname{E}[B_i]\operatorname{E}[B_j] = \operatorname{E}[B_i B_j].$$  You can see how in the next step, the solution evaluates $\operatorname{E}[B_2] = 0$ and $\operatorname{E}[B_3] = 0$.

---

For the sake of completeness, I will quote the question below:

> Let $\{B_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be standard Brownian motion, and let $\tau = \inf \{t > 0 : B_t = -2 \text{ or } 3\}$.  Compute $\operatorname{E}[(2+B_2+B_3)^2]$.

The fact that $\{B_t\}$ is standard Brownian motion is what justifies the claim $\operatorname{E}[B_t] = 0$.  The stopping time $\tau$ is not used in this part of the question but in a later part which I have not quoted here because it is not part of the OP's question.